# MVC Form - Clear ModelState on Back in Browser

Tags: forms, model-view-controller, webforms, asp.net-mvc-2

I have  searchbox in my web app.

I am curious how to clear ModelState when user hits back button. The page retains the 'text-input' from the search results page when the user hits back and goes to home page, which also has a search box.

Before Posting the ques did some initial research here.
I checked similar question on StackOverflow and saw that ModelState.clear() helps you clear he info. But when the user hits "back", the controller does not get called (obv!!) thereby Clear() does not get called.

So what is the best way to get around it.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way would be to use javascript and clear the value when the page is loaded. For example with jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(':text').val('');
    });
</script>
```